# Using Yelp OAuth and Search API bypassing home servers

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, yelp

we are writing a web application on .NET MVC.

It has a textbox and when a user types 'H' we must display all businesses that Yelp thinks are relevant to 'H' (Hotels, Homedepot, etc..)

We are using Yelp Search API 2.0 as described [here](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/authentication)

A standard solution would be to send AJAX request to our server which pulls the access token and other credentials from our database and sends requests to Yelp server using Yelp client [here](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/csharp/YelpAPI/Program.cs), then send the result back to our client.

We can do that. What we would like is to bypass our home server and send OAuth-ed requesed directly to Yelp. I found a solution for this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yelp-developer-support/5bDrWXWJsqY) (their example is here [index.html](https://groups.google.com/group/yelp-developer-support/attach/5fc11c45b80baf2e/index.html?part=0.1))

If we want to pursue this path, we would generate an MVC View in our app that would contain all credential data (access tokens, etc) and use [OAuth.js](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js) and [SHA1.js](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/sha1.js) libraries.

My undesratanding is that it is not a great idea to expose one's credentials like secrets and tokens in a plain view on the client side (this is specifically states on line 15 of the example).

My question is, how can I conseal this secret information and if it is possible at all for all request to be sent directly to Yelp bypassing our home servers.